# I am applying Transfer Learning for my Regression problem. I am using MobileNetV2 and the predicted values give me way too many outputs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I am new to Transfer learning and trying to use pre-trained MobileNetV2 for my regression problem. I want to predict 8 output values, but whenever I try to predict using the trained model, I receive outputs of size 7x7x1280 which is the size of the output layer of MobileNetV2.
Here is the brief code of how I am applying transfer learning to my problem. Also, I am creating two different output layers as my 'output_1' and 'output_2' have a different distributions.

```
# Define MSE model with transfer learning
    base_model_MSE = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    x = base_model_MSE.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    output_1 = Dense(6, activation='sigmoid', name='output_1')(x)
    output_2 = Dense(2, name='output_2')(x)

    # Define the final model with transfer learning
    final_model_MSE = Model(inputs=base_model_MSE.input, outputs=[output_1, output_2])

    # Print the model summary
    final_model_MSE.summary()

    # Freeze the base model layers
    for layer in base_model_MSE.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Print the model summary
    final_model_MSE.summary()

    # Compile the model
    final_model_MSE.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
                            loss={'output_1': 'mse', 'output_1': 'mse'},
                            metrics={'output_2': 'mae', 'output_2': 'mae'})

    # Fit the model
    history_MSE = final_model_MSE.fit(train_data_resized, {'output_1': train_labels[:, :6],
                                                           'output_2': train_labels[:, 6:]},
                                      epochs=25, batch_size=64, validation_data=(
            val_data_resized, {'output_1': val_labels[:, :6], 'output_2': val_labels[:, 6:]}),
                                      verbose=1)
```

Here train_data_resized is of dimensions 4000x224x224x3 and val_data_resized as 1000x224x224x3. When i try to predict 100 test examples using this trained model, I receive predictions of dimension 7x7x1280 (this is the output layer size of original MobileNetV2). I am not sure how can i predict the desired 8 values only instead of 7x7x1280 outputs.

I have not found any relevant resource here so that is why posting my problem.

Answer (score 0):

MobileNetV2 is primarily designed for image classification tasks rather than regression problems but it can be adapted to regression by modifying the output layer as you did. However, the output of the model when predicting is a list of dimension 2 (since you defined two outputs output_1 and output_2 for the model) with each array has the shape of [Number of test samples, 6] and [Number of test samples, 2] so a concatenation of both array will give us the desired 8 values with shape [Number of test samples, 8].

```
train_data_resized = tf.random.normal([4000, 224, 224, 3])
train_labels = tf.random.normal([4000,8])

val_data_resized = tf.random.normal([1000, 224, 224, 3])
val_labels = tf.random.normal([4000,8])

history_MSE = final_model_MSE.fit(train_data_resized, {'output_1': train_labels[:, :6], 'output_2': train_labels[:, 6:]}, epochs=25, batch_size=64, validation_data=(val_data_resized, {'output_1': val_labels[:, :6], 'output_2': val_labels[:, 6:]}), verbose=1)

test_data_resized = tf.random.normal([100, 224, 224, 3])
test_labels = tf.random.normal([100,8])

x = final_model_MSE.predict(test_data_resized)
print(x[0].shape)
print(x[1].shape)

y = np.concatenate((x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
print(y.shape)
```

the output is:

```
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 173ms/step
2
(100, 6)
(100, 2)
(100, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, when i predict, i receive 100x7x7x1280 (100,7,7,1280). I think somehow the predictions are coming from the original output layer of MobileNetV2 (it has output dimension of 7x7x1280) instead of my added output layers. Any idea how it can be solved? @kev_ta

Comment: Can you please check the final output shape when you print the model.summary(). With the code you provided I get the following output: output_1 (Dense)               (None, 6)            774         ['dense_3[0][0]']                                                                                               
 output_2 (Dense)               (None, 2)            258         ['dense_3[0][0]']

Comment: My output layers are also having same dimension: output_1 (Dense) (None, 6) and output_2 (Dense) (None, 2). I don't know why it is not able to predict correctly.